# How to generate buttons based on number of values in a list in kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am very new to kivy and am starting to design an app that my father has asked me to make for him. But I am having troubles with something. I would like to create buttons based on how many elements there are in a list. So for example if I have a list like

```
list_of_buttons = ["button1","button2","button3"]
```

I want to basically get the amount of values in the list using a for loop and then creating a button so something like this

```
for x in list_of_buttons:
      Button(text:x)
```

I would like to somehow make this in the .kv file for later convenience but I am not sure how. Is this even possible? Or am I just hoping for something that can't be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
for x in list_of_buttons:
      Button(text=x)
```

If you want to assign to a variable too:

```
for x in list_of_buttons:
      globals()[x] = Button(text=x)
```

Comment: Even though that is a good way of doing it, you cannot actually use a for loop in the .kv file or atleast it hasn't worked for me.